# TL431 Type2 Compensator derivation

Tags: tl431

I am trying to derive the Type 2 Compensator by using TL431, and I read the C.Basso [document](https://www.onsemi.cn/pub/Collateral/TND381-D.PDF)

and I know how to derive the Type 1 Compensator, but I don't know why adding the capacitor (C2) at the Vfb will generate a pole and get this equation (the red line).

Can someone tell me how to get the red line equation?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Can someone tell me how to get the red line equation?*

The opto-coupler's collector terminal is equivalent to a current source (and not a voltage source). As a current source, it is effectively in parallel with \$R_{pullup}\$. A current source in parallel with a resistor is equivalent to a voltage source in series with that same resistor hence, the output of the opto-coupler is equivalent to this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUnPb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, the transfer function of the resistor and capacitor are this: -

$$\dfrac{\frac{1}{sC_2}}{R_{pullup}+\frac{1}{sC_2}} = \dfrac{1}{1 + sC_2 R_{pullup}}$$

That is the redline term in your equation.

Comment: Hi Andy 

I don't understand what's this sentence mean

The opto-coupler's collector terminal is equivalent to a constant current source and not a voltage source. It is effectively in parallel with Rpullup.

Comment: The "signal" from a collector of a BJT is equivalent to a current source. That's basic BJT theory. For AC analysis, both power rails (Vdd and 0 volts) can be regarded as being joined hence, the collector (a current source) can be regarded as being in parallel with the pull-up resistor connected to signal ground (aka 0 volts).

Comment: Maybe the word "constant" was misleading. I shall remove that word from my answer.

Comment: Hi Andy 

Now, it is more clear to me. 

Thank you